# 'group by' in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with these values.

```
$MyArray = array('2','4','4','4','2','2','0','0','0','0','4');
```

I want do an "array group by" (like in MySql) to only have one occurence of values. I expect something like this

```
$AnotherArray = array('2','4','0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to used  `array_unique` function like this

```
$arrayData=array_unique($MyArray);
```

[Here you can see your desired output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04fb8a929a2970098b270532a04f70daa34a3757)

for more details about `array_unique` [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: actually, like this `$MyArray = array_unique($MyArray);`

Comment: answering a duplicate is kindof nogo